# Python script to batch create folders on a Red Hat Linux system

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I'm trying to batch create a bunch of folders using python on a linux system.

I have written this:

```
for file in os.listdir("./slides"):
    if file.endswith(".svs"):
        gameFileTitle = os.path.splitext(file)[0]

    # define variables

    data = dict(
        Game_Name=file,
        Game_Title=gameFileTitle,
        Local_Tile_Directory='/mnt/tiles/game/',

    commands = """\
        mkdir -p {Local_Tile_Directory}{Game_Title}
        """

    # loop through commands and execute
    for command in commands.splitlines():
        command = command.format(**data) 
        print(command)
```

It is showing me the commands, but it's not creating the actual folders.

Is there a way to get this to create the folders on a linux system(Red Hat)?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? can you explain your original file structure and what you would like the result to be? The indentation there seems wrong and so does the logic

Comment: @Chase Hi thanks, so I am trying to construct a command so that it will, for example,  look like `mkdir - p /mnt/tiles/game/gameTitle1`   But I guess I approached it wrong because it is not running the command, it is just displaying it on screen. But I want it to run it so that I can create a bunch of folders in bulk.

Comment: I'm not concerned about what command you want to run, I want to know how and where you want to create the folders with a full example including directory structure

Answer (score 1):

You can either make the folders within python with `os.mkdir`, or you can pipe the script to `sh` so `sh` can run the commands:

```
python program.py | sh -
```

Comment: oh ok thanks! So I would use `os.mkdir(command)` instead of `print(command)` and it would actually create all the folders instead of just showing me the command to make them?

Comment: No, you would do something like `os.mkdir("/path/to/directory")`.

Comment: Oh ok, my script already creates the path like this `mkdir -p {Local_Tile_Directory}{Game_Title}` , so wouldn't `os.mkdir(command)` work?  Because, as an example,  `print(command)` prints out a line like this: mkdir -p /mnt/tiles/game/StarInvader01

Comment: No, you need to get rid of the `mkdir -p` part for `os.mkdir` to work. `os.mkdir` needs **just** the directory, not the full command.

Comment: Oh I see, so I'd change my line in my script to this: `commands = """\os.mkdir("{Local_Tile_Directory}{Game_Title}")"""`, right?  Thanks!